# .ocx in my Visual studio 2010 project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, activex

How can I include an active x control included in my website project? The active x file  came with hardware to be connected to the computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Project ---> Add Reference ---> COM 
[image: Add Reference]

you can see in this list also all ocx registered in the system .

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the two references I needed. But the website still does not recognize the device and says the active control is missing. There is a place in the html page with classid="clsid:xxxxxxxxxx" .. how can I get the class id of the active x control so I can change this value...

Answer (score 0):

you find the `clsid` in `regedit`, go to the root level , `ctrl+f` , enter control name, look for the `lib` folder.